# Install APK from ADB and bypassing the prompt on Redmi

Tags: adb, backup, installation, apk, xiaomi

Device = Redmi 5 Plus.

I have 250 apps as a `.bak` created by PC app. But the cheater PC app is asking for premium to restore it now. So, I can extract the `.bak` and find my apps.

I wanted to batch install those apks. I tried `adb install apkname.apk` to check if it works. But the phone keeps prompting me to accept the install and countdown starts, or else it will auto deny after countdown finishes. I've also tried 3rd-party app like ApkInstaller but it's the same.

I read many articles and they say it works without prompt. So, why am I getting this issue? How to bypass this prompt automatically?

Comment: there is a similar question i just found searching about it (but not a duplicate ), i see that as me you want a batch/cmd solution but only got a linux one, so here it is: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214145
that is a very complete answer that show how to do it. and this is a very compact and simple one, https://android.stackexchange.com/a/229080 , i just tested it and it still works.

Comment: UPDATE: So, in the end, it seems the problem was the 'MIUI optimization' feature. After I turned it off the batch install command works fine.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `adb install`, you can directly use `package manager` from `adb shell` to install apps. Place `.apk` files in `/data/local/tmp` and make sure files are readable, SELinux context must be `u:object_r:shell_data_file:s0`. Now:

```
~$ cd /data/local/tmp
~$ ls *.apk | xargs -I {} pm install '{}'
```

Another simple root solution is to use some file explorer e.g. MiXplorer to batch install apps. Select all `.apk` files and tap on `Install` from menu.

Comment: Thank you Irfan for answering. But can you explain what the SELinux context here means? And what the commands are doing and what they mean. I tried copying an apk to the 'data/local/tmp' and did the 'adb shell' but after that all the commands are coming "permission denied". And the MiXplorer that you suggested is not free. I tried the other installer but they do ask for the permission.