# adb install-multiple fails with error: [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Split null was defined multiple times]

Tags: adb, linux, lineageos, samsung-galaxy-note-4

I'm trying to install multiple .apk files to my Samsung Note 4, over adb. I'm able to install the same set of files individually using the 'install' command, but when I try to 'install-multiple' I get the following error:

```
adb: failed to finalize session
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Split null was defined multiple times]
```

All my own research on the error turns up issues relating to development, but nothing relating to simply installing some .apks. The actual files do not have any spaces or special characters in their names. When I run the command with tracing enabled, you can see that the command that is actually being executed after expansion is syntactically correct.

```
adb install-multiple /tmp/update_phone/*
+ adb install-multiple /tmp/update_phone/firefox.apk /tmp/update_phone/protonmail.apk /tmp/update_phone/protonvpn.apk /tmp/update_phone/whatsapp.apk
```

Any advice would be heartily appreciated!

Ubuntu 20.04 | adb version 1.0.39 | Samsung Galaxy Note 4 | Lineage OS 17.1

Comment: I think what you want to do is [Batch install apks from computer to Android without actually touching my Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/64353/44325). `adb install-multiple` is for installing [split APKs (single app, multiple APKs)](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits), not multiple different apps.

Comment: Thank you very much @AndrewT. The adb documentation doesn't make this clear at all, but now I know.